# Associative law confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

In this example

$$(\lnot p \lor q) \lor (\lnot p \lor r) \equiv (\lnot p \lor \lnot p) ∨ (q \lor r)$$

I can't seem to see how the associative law is applied here to be able to switch.
Any hint or help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intuitively**

Notice that all the connectives are "or". In general, if you only have or's you can parenthesize the expression any way you want and it doesn't make a difference. This is because any way you parenthesize it, the expression will be true if at least one variable is true, and it will be false if every variable is false.

So I would just think of the expression as

$$¬p∨q ∨ ¬p∨r$$

And then switch the $q$ and $¬p$ (Commutative Law), since intuitively again it doesn't matter what order they're in it (for the same reason as above (consider when true/false)).

Thus we can transform it to

$$(¬p∨¬p) ∨ (q∨r)$$

Comment: oh ok i was so obsessed looking at the parenthesis and comparing with the formula and was not making sense... thank you!

Comment: @SachaE Glad to help!

Comment: if it is using ands i cannot remove the parenthesis and play around as with the or's correct?

Comment: @SachaE If it's all and's, then you can still play around in the same way; the problem is when there's a mix. Then you have to use the distibutive laws